# Using pointer with Boost::bimap

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

In my application I have the following classes:

```
class transaction
{
public:
   .....
}

class src_transaction: public transaction
{
public:
   .....
}

class dst_transaction: public transaction
{
public:
   .....
}
```

I want to construct a bimap, which will take an integer number and a pointer to either src_transaction or dst_transaction.

How can I do that using Boost libraries?
Should I declare the "class transaction" as enable_shared_from_this? If so, should it be unqiue_ptr or shared_ptr?
Because I want to do some operation on the biamp inside either src_transaction or dst_transaction as following:

```
 bimap.inset(12, "Pointer to the current transaction i.e. from the same class");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <boost/bimap.hpp>
   #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
   #include <boost/make_shared.hpp>


    using namespace std;

    class Base{

     public:
       Base(int val):_value(val){}
       int _value;

    };


    class Derv1:public Base{

      public:
         Derv1(int val):Base(val){}

    };


    class Derv2:public Base{

      public:
         Derv2(int val):Base(val){}

    };

  //typedef boost::bimap< int,Base* > bm_type;
    typedef boost::bimap< int,boost::shared_ptr<Base> > bm_type;
    bm_type bm;

    int main()
    {

    //  bm.insert(bm_type::value_type(1,new Derv1(1)));
    //  bm.insert(bm_type::value_type(2,new Derv2(2)));

     bm.insert(bm_type::value_type(1,boost::make_shared<Derv1>(1)));
     bm.insert(bm_type::value_type(2,boost::make_shared<Derv2>(2)));

      cout << "There are " << bm.size() << "relations" << endl;

      for( bm_type::const_iterator iter = bm.begin(), iend = bm.end();
          iter != iend; ++iter )
      {
        // iter->left  : data : int
        // iter->right : data : Base*

        cout << iter->left << " <--> " << iter->right->_value << endl;
      }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks I already did that, but I saw some implementations using boost::shared_ptr and unique_ptr with set and map STL, what's the difference with respect to what you did?

Comment: @HA-AS ok, I have just used plain simple pointers, if you are concerned about release of memory then use of shared pointers would be good. Unique pointers would have the behavior of deleting the memory even if some other pointer is using it.